# Declaration of classes in namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Is it possible to declare a class in C# that is only valid to be used within its namespace?

Example:

```
namespace a
{
    public class Dog
    {
        public void sayHello()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine('hello');
        }
    }
}

namespace b
{
    public class DogWalker        
    {
        public void Walk() 
        {
            Dog dog = new Dog();
            dog.sayHello();
        }
    }
}

namespace a
{
    public class DogWalker
    {
        public void Walk() 
        {
            Dog dog = new Dog();
            dog.sayHello();
        }
    }
}
```

In the case above the DogWalker in Namespace b should throw an error message on compile, but DogWalker in namespace a should be allowed since its in the same namespace as the Dog.

If anyone can point me the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by separating the classes into different assemblies and declaring them as `internal`.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. Is there no way to do this in the same assembly?

Comment: @user1051218: Don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to declare a class in C# that is only valid to be used
>   within its namespace?

Yes. Mark your class as `internal`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx says internal is valid for assemblies, not namespaces.

Comment: @Nayan Please look at the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the 'public' Access modifiers of your classes to 'internal'.